# help for interpreting svm graph

Tags: svm

I have been following a tutorial about SVM with a dataset for OCR located in:
https://github.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/blob/master/letterdata.csv

So far I have done the following:

```
letters<-read.csv("letterdata.csv")
train<-letters[1:16000,]
classifier<-svm(letter~.,data=train,kernel="linear")
plot(clasificador,data=letters,xbox~onpix)
```

and I have obtained a graph like the following:

[image]

So far I know that the X are the support vectors, but what does this graph shows? The values xbox and onpix refers to the size of box x and the onpix to the number of pixels each box has. Is there other way to plot the results of the svm in a more meaningful way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is working right. If you're doing OCR, then your doing multiclass SVMs, so you'd have multiple regions partitioning the 2D plane, each colored differently, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794313/unexpected-results-when-using-scikit-learns-svm-classification-algorithm-rbf-k). But you're picture shows a single region, colored blue.

Another suggestion, since you're doing OCR, use Polynomial kernel and with a soft-margin SVM. Don't use a linear kernel.